# Catch RuntimeException

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, runnable

During coding I want to catch some Exceptions from Runnables.

The code I tried to catch an Exception with:

```
public void fooBar(){
    //nullable value
    final String foo = null;
    try{
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(foo == null){
                    //Only Exception that can be thrown from a Runnable
                    throw new RuntimeException("F.U.B.A.R.");
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        //In my opinion the way to catch this Exception
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

What I Expect to see as an output is:
**F.U.B.A.R.**

The output I'm getting:
**Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: F.U.B.A.R.**

The reason I need this is to put this Exception into my own so I can work with it properly down the line.

Does anyone know how to get the expected output instead of my current?

Comment: The need for this is beyond me, care to elaborate *why* do you want this? BTW you can just simply subclass RuntimeException, then override `getMessage()`)

Comment: This is an example code. The real code is inside an JSP project. My goal is to not create any exceptions that would kill the program. All exceptions/errors should be caught and eventually be shown to the user on the JSP page.

Comment: This is not the proper way to handle exceptions between threads. In your case instead of extending Runnable you should use java.util.concurrent.Callable.

Comment: This whole piece of code is executed in a class that extends TimerTask. Is it possible to use callable there too?

Comment: JSPs creating threads? Stop now. This ways leads to madness and pain.

Comment: Thank you for the constructive and helpful reaction.

Comment: All the answers are correct, but none of them _explicitly_ says something that they all ought to have said.  The `System.out.println(...)` statement in your example is never executed.  The output that you see is not coming from the exception handler that you wrote; it comes from the _default exception handler_ of the new thread that you created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because constructing Runnable and executing .start() between try and catch - did not throw exception. Runtime exception raised later, when thread executing "run" method.

Comment: Even if I call the #run() I still get Both the System.out AND the "Exception in thread..." message

Comment: You can use try/catch inside "run" method

Answer (score 2):

Your current catch block catches exceptions on the main thread while your exception is thrown on the other thread. It won't work. You have to

- [set up your own exception handler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler-java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler-) for the new thread
- or move the try-catch block to the body of the `run()` method

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because of two threads.The exception of one thread cannot be caught by another.

In your case,you are trying to catch an exception which may occur when starting the thread by the main thread `new Thread(new Runnable() {--- }).start();`

**You need to catch the exception inside the Thread-0**

```
            @Override
            public void run() {
             try{
                if(foo == null){
                    //Only Exception that can be thrown from a Runnable
                    throw new RuntimeException("F.U.B.A.R.");
                }
               }catch(Exception ex){
               //In my opinion the way to catch this Exception
               System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
              }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

As many above/below me have pointed out you are attempting to catch an exception in one thread with a completely different thread, this means that the [default exception handler is catching and handling it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html). You can change that if you wish, but it is generally a better idea to catch the exception in the thread you are working with and handle it there.

If you need the two threads to talk to each other then you have a few options, such as the spawned thread catching the exception and passing passing it over, to using an [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), calling get on the [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) and seeing if it throws a [ExecutionException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutionException.html).

You have mentioned that you are using [TimerTask](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html)s. If you can move to [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) then you can use the Future method. If not then you are going to have to catch the exception the TimerTask and pass the fact if failed back to the main thread.